# Generating wordlist permutations from existing files

Tags: text-processing

I have two wordlist files; the first contains:

```
John
Jerry
Jim
```

the second contains:

```
one
two
three
```

The files are several thousand lines each, not just the 3 words above. How can I generate permutations so that I get the following output?

```
Johnone
Johntwo
Johnthree
Jerryone
Jerrytwo
Jerrythree
..
..
..
```

Comment: Do you want all the combinations, or k (random) combinations? (several thowsnad)^2 is a big output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), being careful to pass the second file as the *first* parameter:

```
awk '(NR==FNR) { a[NR]=$0 } (NR != FNR) { for (i in a) { print $0 a[i] } }' file2 file1
```

This saves all of file2 into an array `a`, then loops through file1 (implicitly) and loops through every element of `a`, printing the current line of file1 followed by the saved line from file2. The ordering is not guaranteed, but it's still valid permutation.

Sample run:

```
$ cat file1
John
Jerry
Jim
Jeff

$ cat file2
one
two
three
four

$ awk '(NR==FNR) { a[NR]=$0 }  (NR != FNR) { for (i in a) { print $0 a[i] } }' file2 file1
Johnfour
Johnone
Johntwo
Johnthree
Jerryfour
Jerryone
Jerrytwo
Jerrythree
Jimfour
Jimone
Jimtwo
Jimthree
Jefffour
Jeffone
Jefftwo
Jeffthree
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for w1 in $(cat file1)
do 
  for w2 in $(cat file2)
  do
    word=${w1}${w2}
    echo ${word} >> permutationfile
  done
done
```

for different formatting options, you can play with `printf` instead of `echo` command